# First occurrence on every line vi/vim/sed etc

Tags: regex, vim, sed, awk, vi

Using VI replacing the first occurrence/instance is pretty simple.

```
    :%s/search/replace/args
```

but, here is my data set in a .csv format/file:

```
"192.168.2.1","www.google.com","2009/01/11_10:00"," What a great website"
"192.168.2.2/driving/is/fun","-","2009/03/22_00:00","Driving website"
"192.168.2.4/boating/is/crazy","-","2009/03/22_00:00","Boating Website"
"192.168.2.5","www.cars.com","2009/04/27_00:00","What a good car website"
```

so, you'll notice in the first line, there are 4 columns, this is the ideal line for the .csv format.

However, in the second line, there are 4 columns, but the first column only accepts ip addresses and nothing more, so 192.168.2.2/driving/is/fun must be removed or seperated with a "," .csv delimter.

In vi, I was able to use the following:

```
    :/^"\d\{,3}\.\d\{,3}\.\d\{,3}\.\d\{,3}\//s/\//","/
```

which does the following:

- /^"\d{,3}.\d{,3}.\d{,3}.\d{,3}/ - Sets an anchor to start the search at the first IP with a forward slash /. For example, line 2: "192.168.2.2/
- /s///","/ - replaces the / at the end of the IP address and substitutes it with a .csv delimiter ","

This works great in VI/VIM, replaces exactly what I need one line at a time. However, the data set is much much larger and manually using the following vi search and replace is time consuming. I am looking to script it or find an alternative solution because VI/VIM will only do it one line at a time, the following :s/search/replace/g replaces every / on the line changing the date column in addition.

Obviously, I've tried the following:

Adding the % for the whole file inside of the start of the substitution like so:

```
    :/^"\d\{,3}\.\d\{,3}\.\d\{,3}\.\d\{,3}\//%s/\//","/
```

which highlights every entry I need to modify but errors out:

```
    E492: Not an editor command: /^"\d\{,3}\.\d\{,3}\.\d\{,3}\.\d\{,3}\//%s/\//
```

which is rather confusing.

I would ultimately like to use sed/perl to script the editing of the whole file in one shot.

so..

"192.168.2.2/ --> "192.168.2.2","

First occurrence on every line.

Any help will be greatly appreciated..

Thanks!

Comment: Just a general protip: you can use pretty much any character for delimiting your patterns. If you use pipe, for example, you will not have to escape slashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ViM, try:

```
 :%s/^\("\d\{,3}\.\d\{,3}\.\d\{,3}\.\d\{,3}\)\(\/[^"]\)/\1","\2
```

That is, instead of a search/substitute I use a global (`%` is shortcut for `1,$` i.e *from first line to last line*) substitution. I moved your search pattern into the substitution pattern and capture the ip address and the path in separate groups. Then replace them back, squeezing `","` in between.

Comment: Nice work.. Perfect.. can you explain what I missed or what you've added, just so I understand/learn?

Comment: I added it in the answer. Let me know if I can clarify it further.

Comment: PEZ, I understand the % = global, but the grouping and the use of the "back squeezing" isn't working for me.. I know what you did, I see that it works. I just need to understand how the syntax is read/used etc.. I don't fully understand how this section works: \(\/[^"]\)/\1","\2 because I want to apply another scenario where I have the IP "192.168.2.1:8080 and need to use what "You" had to substitute the : with ","

Comment: It's a bit hard to see through all those backslashes. =) ... Parens form catch groups. In ViM default is that you must prepend parens with a backslash to give them the grouping magic. So the part you have picked out there is the second catch group which catches the slash followed by anything that isn't a `"` then it's the separator `/` with the substitution pattern to the right. `\1` represent anything that is catched in the first group and `\2` thusly the second group. In between it's the literal string `","`. I hope I at least avoided to muddle it further. =)

Comment: PEZ, awesome explanation, I'm good, I've made my next substiution: %s/^\("\d\{,3}\.\d\{,3}\.\d\{,3}\.\d\{,3}\)\(\:[^"]\)/\1","\2 it works great! Huge time saver! Your work is greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 4):

In vi/vim you can specify the search range that you want to replace over. In this case you want `:%s` to replace in all lines:

```
:%s/search/replace/g
```

You can also specify:

```
:2,5s/search/replace/g      Replace on lines 2-5
:.,$s/search/replace/g      Replace from current line (.) to last line ($)
:.,+3s/search/replace/g     Replace on the current line (.) and the two next lines (+3)
:g/^asd/s/search/replace/g  Replace on lines starting with 'asd'.
```

You can then combine this with a simpler pattern to make the replacements you want throughout the whole file:

```
:%s/^\("[^/"]*\)[^"]*"/\1"/
```

This will remove everything after the IP address from the first entry in the CSV.

```
:%s/^\("[^/"]*\)\/\([^"]*\)"/\1","\2/
```

This will split the first entry into the IP address and the remainder, though this will only be done for those lines where there is a slash after the IP.
What you were trying to do was find the pattern, go to that line and then replace. Adding the '%' in that case made the command invalid.

Comment: John Lawrence, thanks for the reply.. "(:%s/search/replace/g )" doesn't work. When using the g - global option it strips out the forward slashes in the date as well and not just the forward slash at the end of the IP's, it takes out every slash in the file. If you only use the :%s it takes out every forward slash in the line removing the directory path and dates, etc..

Comment: That is correct. Adding the 'g' replaces all matches in the line whereas without it just replaces the first match. That is why I left the 'g' off for the regex you should use. Sorry if it wasn't clear, the first bits of my answer were there more for general reference.

Comment: Even using :%s/\//","/ for the first occurrence of the forward slash removes a forward slash on line items that don't have a forward slash after the IP resulting in removing the first occurrence of a forward slash somewhere else in the line, like the date.

Comment: Also, this data set consists of roughly 1,000 lines.. pin-pointing the lines using set number etc.. would be just as time consuming as doing it manually. the range section hasn't been much help either.

Comment: John, this: :%s/^\("[^/"]*\)[^"]*"/\1"/ was extremely close, except on the lines where the ip is: 192.168.2.1/driving/is/fun it substitutes the / with "," but also deletes the  driving/is/fun.. very close

Comment: I think I misunderstood exactly what you were wanting to do. I had thought you wanted to remove everything after the slash. I think that the second regex I have added to my answer will do what you want!

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you want with a simpler pattern:

```
s/^\("[^/"]*\)[^"]*"/\1"/
```

This is: match start of line, start a match group: match a `"`, match any number of characters that are not a slash and are not a `"`, close the match group, match any number of characters that are not a `"`, and match a `"`.  Replace with the match group contents plus a `"`.

The above pattern should be pretty simple to script.  Here is a Python example.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print("Usage: log_file_cleaner <input_file> <output_file>")
    sys.exit(1)

pat = re.compile(r'^("[^/"]*)[^"]*"')

with open(sys.argv[1]) as in_f, open(sys.argv[2], "w") as out_f:
    for line in in_f:
        line = re.sub(pat, r'\1"', line)
        out_f.write(line)
```

Note: you need a recent version of Python to do one `with` that does two `open()` calls.  If you are stuck on Cygwin, you can edit the above to two nested `with` statements, each one doing a single `open()` call.

Comment: steveha, thanks for the reply.

s/^\("[^/"]*\)[^"]*"/\1"/
^^ only highlights/selects everything in-between the two "".  

so it highlights " 192.168.2.1" and "192.168.2.2/driving/is/fun"

Comment: Do you understand what a match group is, and how it works?  Yes, the whole pattern matches the "/driving/is/fun" stuff but the match group omits it.  And, if you need it to reject white space after the first quote mark, I could edit the pattern to do that, but your example didn't indicate that this would be needed.